# React Icons - pull icon dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [React Icons](https://react-icons.github.io/icons?name=fa) and it works great, but would it be possible to *dynamically* pull an icon from a React loop? For example, let's say I have this code:

```
import { FaCodepen, FaLinkedinIn, FaGithub } from 'react-icons/fa'

[...]

const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query SocialQuery {
    allContentfulSocial {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          link
          icon
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)

[...]

<div className="column is-half">
  <div className="level social-icons">
    {
      data.allContentfulSocial.edges.map((edge) => (
        <div className="level-item">
          <a
            href={edge.node.link}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            title={edge.node.title}
          >
            <FaCodepen /> // <-- is it possible to dynamically pull an icon here?
          </a>
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

So in my case, I have three social icons, namely: *CodePen*, *GitHub*, and *LinkedIn*. I was thinking of doing something like this from the code above:

```
<edge.node.icon />
```

But this didn't work since it threw an error. I was thinking they would have a use-case somewhere in their documentation, but I didn't find anything useful.

Would anyone have run across this issue before? Appreciate the help!

Note: I am using *GatsbyJS* for my project, which is why there is a *GraphQL* query above pulling from my *Contentful* CMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a simple keyed object:

```
const icons = {
  codepen: FaCodepen,
  linkedIn: FaLinkedIn,
  ...
}


const PostIcon = ({iconName}) => {
  const Icon = icons[iconName];
  return <Icon />
}
```

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes! This seems to be working fine for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
const data = [
    {..., icon: FaCodepen},
    ...
];

data.map(({..., icon: Icon}) => (
    <Icon />
));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).